# diagonal line collision in js

Tags: javascript, math

im trying to make a program that makes a bunch of lines connecting at random points. im trying to make it so there is no overlapping lines but i cant figure out how to detect if any collision happens on the diaginal line

```
        let players = [];
        function Player(beginPathX,beginPathY,endPathX,endPathY,lineDistance,slope)
        {
            this.beginPathX = beginPathX;
            this.beginPathY = beginPathY;
            this.endPathX = endPathX;
            this.endPathY = endPathY;
            this.lineDistance = lineDistance||0;
            this.slope = slope||0;
        }
        players.push(new Player(100,100,200,200,0,0));

        function testLine()
        {
            for(let i = 0; i < players.length;i++)
            {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(players[i].beginPathX,players[i].beginPathY);
                ctx.lineTo(players[i].endPathX,players[i].endPathY);
                ctx.stroke();
                players[i].lineDistance = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((players[0].endPathX-players[0].beginPathX),2)+Math.pow((players[0].endPathY-players[0].beginPathY),2)));
                players[i].slope = (players[0].endPathY-players[0].beginPathY/players[0].endPathX-players[0].beginPathX);
            }
        }
```

Comment: My first guess is that you can compute the intersection of the lines on which the line segments lie, and then see if the intersection point is falls on both segments. I think "point (x, y) lies on line segment (x0, y0) to (x1, y1)" is just x0 <= x and x <= x1 and y0 <= y and y <= y1, but you'll want to check it.

Answer (score 0):

In case only `to be crossed or not to be crossed` matters (=actual coordinates of the cross-point are not required), logic can be simple.

#### Brief explanation

Supposing there are `line1` and `line2`.

1. The endpoints of `line2` distribute in both sides of `line1`.
2. The endpoints of `line1` distribute in both sides of `line2`.

When these two conditions meet simultaneously, The lines are crossing.

#### Implementation

Therefore the detection function can be

```
// For given Line1(x0,y0)-(x1,y1) and Line2(x2,y2)-(x3,y3).

function crossing(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {

  const bothSides = (x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) => {
    const n =[-(y1 - y0), x1 - x0]
    return (n[0] * (x2 - x0) + n[1] * (y2 - y0)) * (n[0] * (x3 - x0) + n[1] * (y3 - y0)) < 0  
  }

  return bothSides(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) && bothSides(x2, y2, x3, y3, x0, y0, x1, y1);
}
```